# How to create an azure web service and use existing sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I'm working on an exercise and i want a help. So far I have to created an MVC4 Internet Application using C# and uploaded it to azure as a web site (custom create with sql server). Now I want to create a web service to use the same database that my web application is using. How I can do it?

I found an option when you create a new project (C#->Cloud Project-> Windows Azure Cloud Service)

Note that then i want to use the web service with workflow based service

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Connections to SQL Azure are just Connection Strings.  This isn't any different than creating applications on premises or hosting them elsewhere.  Get the connection string of your existing Azure SQL Database and then use that when setting up your database calls in your web service project.  You can get the connection string from the Windows Azure Management portal.  Dig down to the database and there will be a Show Connection Strings option on the dashboard page for the database.   See this documentation if you aren't familiar with working with connection strings Azure SQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336282.aspx

Note that Azure SQL Databases do not support integrated windows authentication, so the connection string will contain the username and password.  You may want to look into securing that information in your configuration.